# My Debian /proc/cmdline gets reset every time I restart

Tags: boot, kali-linux, grub2, reboot

Every time I restart my computer (running Kali Linux), the `/proc/cmdline` file gets reset, and reconfigures the root to `/dev/sdb1`, which leads to the boot failing (as `/dev/sdb1` does not exist), and so every time I have to turn it on, I have to edit the file and set the root again to `/dev/sda1`.

How can I make it so the system doesn't mess up that file? It's a bit of a nuisance having to edit the boot settings every time I restart my machine.

By the way, I have tried using `chattr +i /proc/cmdline` to manually lock the file, but I get an error (`chattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device while reading flags on cmdline`)

Comment: `/proc` is a virtual filesystem, it is a "view into the (running) kernel" not persistent stuff. You seem to need to reconfigure your bootloader, not mess with these files.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro no, it contains the command line options given to the kernel, typically by GRUB (on a PC).

Comment: I'm not sure what it is you're doing, by I don't think it's even possible to edit `/proc/cmdline` on a running system, it wouldn't make much sense. Writing to it returns `-EIO` (Input/output error).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are using Kali Linux you are probably also using Grub2

The problem is not with the `/proc/cmdline` file as it is a virtual file which is recreated at boot time.

You need to reconfigure grub2 to pass the parameter to the kernel.

So edit `/etc/default/grub`, you should see a line named `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=`

Add inside the quotation mark `root=/dev/sda1` and save, then do `update-grub` in a terminal and you are done.